# Bitwise macro not working (Avr C)

Tags: c, macros, bitwise-operators, avr

I'm facing some issues with this macro:

```
#define SHOW(val)   PORTB = ((PORTB & 0xFF^OUT_PINS) | ((val) & OUT_PINS));
```

Let's say I have (defined earlier)

```
#define OUT_PINS 0b00011110
```

and `PORTB` has some values on other bits that I want to preserve.

The macro was intended to apply `val` to `PORTB` (`OUT_PINS` only) and leave the rest alone.

However, I'm just getting 1's on all output pins.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you properly set up the port direction register for `PORTB`?

Comment: Yep, turns out this was a stupid mistake in my other macro. I'll put an answer as warning for others :D

Comment: `0xFF^OUT_PINS` takes a while to settle at the reader. (Remember code should be readable.) Instead, `~OUT_PINS` makes immediately clear what the intention is.

Comment: @glglgl I had ~ before, but it didn't work (well, now we know why), so I tried a different way...

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this was a silly mistake.

```
#define SEG_DOT     _BV(PB1)
#define SEG_DIAG1   _BV(PB2)
#define SEG_DIAG2   _BV(PB3)
#define SEG_HORIZ   _BV(PB4)

#define BUTTON      _BV(PB0)

#define OUT_PINS    SEG_DOT | SEG_DIAG1 | SEG_DIAG2 | SEG_HORIZ
#define IN_PINS     BUTTON

#define BTN()       (PINB & BUTTON == 0)
#define SHOW(val)   PORTB = ((PORTB & ~OUT_PINS) | ((val) & OUT_PINS));
```

As you can see the `OUT_PINS` macro does not have brackets around it, so when it's expanded in the `SHOW` macro, it all becomes a huge nonsense.

Two possible fixes:

```
#define OUT_PINS    (SEG_DOT | SEG_DIAG1 | SEG_DIAG2 | SEG_HORIZ)
```

OR

```
#define SHOW(val)   PORTB = ((PORTB & ~(OUT_PINS)) | ((val) & (OUT_PINS)));
```

I like the first fix better, because the second looks very Lispy. Though, why not use both, after all.

Comment: You should apply both. Always define macros in a way so they don't expose surprises. It should be possible to do `SHOW(val1 | val2 | val3)`. You can never have enough `()`s at macros; it is one reason they are frowned upon.

Comment: @glglgl so.. should I use an inlined function instead, maybe?

Comment: "because the second looks very Lispy" -- silly reason. Macro parameters should always be parenthesized if they can be misinterpreted due to precedence. Lose the `;` at the end of SHOW ... that should be at the point of invocation.

Comment: @MightyPork If this solution does what it is supposed to, you can happily keep it. Many people think macros are bad per se - they can be very confusing, and then they start to become bad. (Just as many people think `goto` is bad per se, which isn't true anyway. It's only when you abuse it it becomes bad. But then, other things can be abused as well for bad things.)

Comment: @glglgl whenever a macro can be substituted by an inline function this should be done. Reason #1 type safety #2 parameter evaluation errors (the above problem) #3 Speed - parameters will not be evaluated multiple times. especially on µCs with memory mapped IOs that are usually declared as `volatile`, this may cause multiple readouts and calculates of intermediate results. In some cases this may even cause problems, when a parameter value is expected to be constant during macro evaluation but changes due to another readout. So better learn to write clean code from beginning.